# Get HomeTeam ID and AwayTeam ID of each game for a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables:

Table 1 called teams: that contains different columns like Team_ID, Team_Name... etc.

table 2 called matches: that contains different columns like Match_ID, Home, Away, Match_Date.

Home and away are the names of 2 teams that I generated, 
I tried different queries to generate a result where I have teams ID instead of teams names
for example:

```
SELECT t1.Home,t2.Away from  

(SELECT a.Team_ID AS Home, b.Match_Date from teams a
INNER JOIN matches b ON a.Team_Name=b.Home
Where b.Match_Date="2020-05-29 23:59:59") t1,

(SELECT a.Team_ID AS Away, b.Match_Date from teams a
INNER JOIN matches b on a.Team_Name=b.Away
Where b.Match_Date="2020-05-29 23:59:59") t2;
```

But it didn't give me the result that I'm looking for
and After getting the result, I just to want filter it using a specific date like WHERE Match_Date= "date"

An image to clarify what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two `join`s on `teams` (one for the home team and the other for the away team), and a `where` clause to filter on the match date:

```
select th.team_id home, ta.team_id away, m.match_date
from matches m
inner join teams th on th.team_name = m.home
inner join teams ta on ta.team_name = m.away
where m.match_date = 'date1'
```

Note that you should not be storing the team *name* in `matches`, but the team *id* instead (which, presumably, is the primary key of `teams`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works perfectly as I wanted, but I just want to know about something, is it considered bad practice if I add the Team name for home and away teams in the matches table instead of id ? or you think it's fine

Comment: @AliZgheib: it is bad practice. You should always use the primary key column as a reference in other tables. This guarantees integrity, and allows setting up proper foreign keys.

Comment: I thought so, thank you for the help a lot, and I hope you a nice day :)